# Gradle: How to define a second way to build a multiproject

Tags: java, gradle

I need some help with a Multiproject with Gradle.
This is the structure of my project.

PRoot

│

├── P2

│   ...

│   └── build.gradle

├── P1

│   ...

│   └── build.gradle

│

├── build.gradle

└── settings.gradle

Everything works fine

Now i need a second way to build my project. I created 2 new Files:

PRoot

│

├── P2

│   ...

│   └── build.gradle

├── P1

│   ...

│   └── build.gradle

│

├── build.gradle

├── settings.gradle

├── build2.gradle

└── settings2.gradle

Then started Gradle with

build --build-file=build_dev.gradle --settings-file=settings_dev.gradle

but that doesn't work, even without changing anything in the two files

How is the best way to do something like this?